# Creating dynamic buttons using two layouts in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, button, dynamic

I would like to create dynamic buttons in my main activity. The buttons are in a separate activity with an own layout file. I can show you my test project. I guess it could be better, but I am still a beginner in this field. ;-)

This is my main activity. Nothing special:

```
package de.example.testprojekt;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true; 
}
}
```

I have another Class with following code:

```
package de.example.testprojekt;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class TestClass extends LinearLayout {

LayoutInflater inflator;


public TestClass (Context context) {
    super (context);
    initialize();
}

public TestClass (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super (context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

public TestClass (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super (context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialize();
}

void initialize() {
    inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflator.inflate(R.layout.secondary_activity, this);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    setupLayout();      
}

Button button1;
String TAG = "tag";
private void setupLayout () {
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Log.e(TAG,"test");

        }
    });
}
}
```

And here are my two XML Files:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <de.example.testprojekt.TestClass
                android:id="@+id/mainCtrl1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

            <de.example.testprojekt.TestClass
                android:id="@+id/mainCtrl2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
         </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

And the second one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after.  Can you provide some drawings?

Comment: Sure. Here is a screentshot.
[link](http://s7.directupload.net/images/120719/yi6jc6ui.jpg)
As you can see, I have two buttons. They are generated in the first XML File and initialized in the second XML File.
I would like to add and remove those buttons dynamic while my application is running. But the buttons should use
the XML as layout because I want to add more views to the second layout. 
Is it possible to enable and disable the buttons in the main activity instead of the xml activity?
I hope you understand my request :-)

Answer (score 0):

IF you're doing what I think you're doing this might come in handy:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

ViewGroup allows you to dynamically add / remove views AFAIK. If you have those Buttons attached to a ViewGroup (in your case your two layouts) I would just call something like

layout.removeView(button1)

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:** just found this while looking into some more dynamic stuff. Seems even more powerful than viewgroup since it takes place AFTER all the layouts have been built and such.
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/dynamic-styling-of-views-on-android/1131

Answer (score 0):

For this u simply use visiblity for those buttons for 
removing

```
Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and for adding

```
Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```